# Broadcast para leer botones de volumen

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, keypressevent

estoy teniendo un problema con mi broadcast.

No estoy pudiendo hacer que al presionar cualquier boton de volumen (vol+/-) se muestre mi Toast.
Esto es lo mas importante de mi manifiesto:

```
    <receiver android:name="Broadcast.b_Botones" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

y este es el simple codigo de mi broadcast:

```
public class b_Botones extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context,"arranca", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
```

Al presionar las te clas de volumen,no sucede nada, busque y la verdad no encontre nada que me solucione el problema.
De yapa, si saben como capturar que boton de los dos se preciono, me serviria demasiado!

Esto es lo que puedo recuperar del logcat

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola buena tarde, te regresa algún error en el log ??

Comment: Hola! @Serna , ahi edite la pregunta y subi algo que encontre en el logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta a mi pregunta es simple, pero van a tener que pensas una solución para sus códigos.

Yo cuento con android 8 en el teléfono, el problema? 
Es que a partir de android 7 hubieron cambios en la seguridad y se añadieron restricciones, pero con android 8 se agregaron aun mas restricciones, por lo cual no se permiten crear determinados tipos de broadcast y que queden funcionando permanentemente, **si no que hay que registrarlos al momento que se deseen usar o necesiten, y una ves finalizada la aplicación deben eliminarse.**

Para mas información les dejo en enlace a la documentación de Google

[BROADCAST](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts)
[BROADCAST 2](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-recievers)

Answer (score 0):

También puedes utilizar este código, este lo utilizo para determinar el volumen.

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
 AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

 if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)){ 
 Log.i(TAG, "VOLUME UP PRESSED!"); 
 Toast.makeText(context,"arranca", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }
 else if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN))
 { 
 Log.i(TAG, "VOLUME DOWN PRESSED!"); 
 Toast.makeText(context,"arranca", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 } 
 return true; 
 }
```

Comment: Hola!, gracias por responder. Este codigo que pusiste, entiendo que sirve para las Activities, no estaria sirviendo para mi broadcast, o si?, necesito implementar algo?

Comment: Deberia funcionar para fragment solo debe cambiar el getApplicationContext() por getActivity(). Eso se encuentra en la segunda linea

Comment: mmm claro entiendo, el problema es que mi pregunta esta basada para un broadcast, necesitaria saber cuando se precionaron botones, para activar mi aplicacion cuando esta cerrada

Comment: Oh bueno. vale.